# Using Javascript To Block IP Address After Set Period Of Time

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for a way to block a person's IP address with Javascript after a set period of time. I need this script for my One Time Offer page which customers are redirected to after they make a small purchase. When people visit the page, there's a countdown timer at the top that tells them that the offer expires in 30 minutes. But they can still come back after the 30 minutes is up because there's nothing there to stop them. Is there a way to fix this problem with Javascript? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By javascript, do you mean client-side javascript?

Comment: It's for a web page so I guess it's client-side. But I'm not a coder so I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Given they have just made a purchase, you probably already have their details in your server-side database, don't you? So if the user tries to work around the limit on the client side you can still respond with a page that says the time is up.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like something I would use javascript for. The details depend on your language, but I think the general idea is to log their ip on the server when they initially visit the page, then then refuse them from the server side when their time limit is up. Two languages that seem more appropriate would be PHP and ASP. You would also need some way to persist their ip which means some sort of database like MySQL.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. So how would go about doing this with PHP?

Comment: The foundation of making this work is not PHP, it's the database. All you need to do is insert their ip into the database. You can use PHP's MySQL bindings using mysqli interface and the PHP can access the ip through the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` global variable. Where is your page hosted?

Comment: I'm using shared Linux hosting from Godaddy.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are a number of steps to get the set up and working properly, and every host has their database specifics setup a little differently. I'd be happy to try and help you further but is there another place I might be able to work with you on this?

Comment: Maybe some kind of live chat?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the user to this ***offer page*** after they have made a purchase. So, I can safely assume that you assign each purchase a *unique* **Purchase ID** of some sort.
If you aren't, I'd suggest that you do because that would help you on the long run in keeping track of each purchase. 
Once you do that, put a condition on the **Purchase ID** for the offer.

There are many ways to that:

- Use **PHP** and create a *cookie* with a 30min lifespan. [See how](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fphp%2Ffunc_http_setcookie.asp&ei=rFuXVaC9F4u6uAS-wIHIAw&usg=AFQjCNGtvFjc0NzJ7FcSCz3TTPx2bkG6EA&sig2=OyZwAgRn7K0ifCRPWNx7pw&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E)
- Like many people suggested, *javascript* isn't the best way to go about it but if you still want to go with that option, you could use [JS Cookies](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjs%2Fjs_cookies.asp&ei=r1yXVa2pKo6UuAS4mZvYCw&usg=AFQjCNFlmltWi2Y2BRV8kwTw2orRW5vp2A&sig2=dEqbzfVfgvCc4XOU-YwXzw&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E)

Hope this helps.